# How to create specific user log files in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, logging, active-directory

I know there are question that is already answered however those are the log files I don't need and I can't get it to work. This part of PowerShell is something I didn't learned yet. I'm trying to do the following: I wrote a script to create users, mailboxes, folders etc however I want to enable a log file, just simple and plain.

Something only certain people can access and where the log files have the following info, for example: **PSmith created on 01/29/2019 the user account JDoe.**

How can I do this? I tried a lot found online however I have to rewrite my whole script for some to work.

Comment: Are you referring to some audit logs ?

Comment: @PrasoonKarunanV - We want to monitor who has created an account, it could be exported to a hidden .txt-file stored on another disk (or something else, but i'm checking what's the best solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need something like this, if not please provide more code.

```
$creator = (get-aduser $env:username | Select Name).Name
$date = get-date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y"
```

I believe you have the `$user` in your script.

```
$log = $creator + "created on " + $date + " the user account " + $user.Name
Out-File $log "C:\temp\log.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you, however I'm getting the following error: `Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "C:\temp\log.csv" does not belong to the set "unknown,string,unicode,bigendianuni
code,utf8,utf7,utf32,ascii,default,oem" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp\log.ps1:7 char:15
+ Out-File $log "C:\temp\log.csv"` when I try to remove the second `get-date` and change `$log` to `Out-File -filepath "C:\temp\log.csv"` and re-run the script than I won't getting errors

Comment: However, when I open the csv file the only thing I see in the first column is: `ÿþ`.

Comment: This is a bit redundant: `(get-aduser $env:username | Select Name).Name` either use: `$creator = Get-Aduser $env:USERNAME | Select-Object -Expandproperty Name` or shorter `$creator = (Get-Aduser $env:USERNAME).Name`

Comment: @LotPings - I'm still having this error: `Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "C:\temp\log.csv" does not belong to the set "unknown,string,unicode,bigendianuni
code,utf8,utf7,utf32,ascii,default,oem" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp\log.ps1:7 char:15
+ Out-File $log "C:\temp\log.csv"`

Comment: @signedup My comment just addressed the first command. See `Get-Help Out-File` the 1st parameter is either -Path or -Encoding. You can use `$log | Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\log.csv"` or `Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\log.csv" -Inputobject $log`

Comment: @LotPings I forgot to put the pipe line after $log! :) Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. Edit: Is there a way to encrypt as well? Edit2: However, it overwrites the file, it doesn't add the second log. < Solved by -append!

Comment: Encrypt the script/log? Either way this is a new question you should research first and if unsuccessful ask a new question to have a broader audience and give others the opportunity to answer and gain reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option: you can [enable transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-6) which would log every single command that is entered at the console potentially creating a huge file but you would have to filter for the specific messages yourself.

There are tools like microsoft orchestrator that would run your script and log the results automatically but those are expensive other than that you would pretty much have to build the logging yourself.

My suggestion would be to send the message to the [windows event log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Write-EventLog?view=powershell-5.1)s. This way you dont have to manage the log files, windows does it for you with date and time stamps. This would also make it audit and query friendly.