# Write, encrypt & decrypt .csv log file?

Tags: powershell, logging, encryption

> This community has helped me along the way, which I'm thankful for!

However, in my previous question I had an issue with log files that is fixed now.
I have added the log files feature because I want to track who created users.
The thing is everyone is allowed to **read and modify**, is it possible to encrypt the .csv-file and make it read-only, except for the script, because the script needs to write the log files. I have Googled, but those are not the right solution, since they encrypt the file using AES but that's not what I need because other users needs to access (read) the file as well.

```
$creator = (Get-Aduser $env:USERNAME).samAccountName
$date = get-date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y"
$log = $creator + " created on " + $date + " the user account " + $userid
$log | Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\log.csv" -Append
```

Or is there another way that I might overlook?

[How to create specific user log files in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419372/how-to-create-specific-user-log-files-in-powershell/)

Comment: If you want to prevent undetected modification, but still want to allow shared read-access, you'll want to look into _signing_ the data rather than _encrypting_ it

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Where should I start?

Comment: I dont think you should Sign a log file. This really sounds like a Windows Permissions issue. You should set the permission to allow the users read rights and administrators modify delete rights

Comment: @ArcSet That’s above my rights. I can’t modify the permission because the script is used by our servicedesk users. They have to work inside it. No possibility to unlock, write the log file and encrypt it?

Comment: As @Kiran mentioned in your other thread, writing to Windows Event Logs seems like a good solution as it will allow simple insert and prevent unauthorized modification. The script will not be able to modify the event logs (only add), but that doesn't seem like a feature you need, right?

Comment: @Rich Moss I don’t know if we even have that kind of privilege. However the solution in my other thread to write to csv is something I really adore. They don’t have enabled full Windows Event Logs, so I don’t think that’s the solution I need, although for this particular thing.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand the whole story here. You have a log. You want to Read, Write and Encrypt. YET you want others to be able to read it. You also cant change the permissions on the file so that you can read write and modify, yet others can only read? 
So what is it you exactly are looking for because i am confused. Maybe you might need to edit your post with the limitations and what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @ArcSet I’m sorry for the confusion. What I’m trying to do is somewhat you have in Excel when you save the sheet you can give it a password for editing later, however you have an option because the file is password protected to only read the file (that’s for my colleagues). If there is another option I’m missing than I would love to know which one that is. No super high privilege rights.